# set a default selection for r console request for a selection (dynamically install packages if required)

Tags: r

The following is r console output requesting to select weather to install the required package or not.

[image]

Is there a way to set selection = 1 always?

It's required to install packages if already not there to run the `train`() in side for loop

```
require(caret)
set.seed(1234)
df =data.frame(a=1:10, target=sample(c(1,0), size = 10, replace = T)  )

splitIndex <- createDataPartition(df$target, p = .50, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainSplit <- df[ splitIndex,]
testSplit <- df[-splitIndex,]
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

cc= c('C5.0Cost' , 'rpartCost' , 'deepboost' , 'fda' , 'glm' , 'glmStepAIC' , 'lm' , 'lmStepAIC' , 'avNNet' , 'earth' , 'gcvEarth' , 'nnet' , 'pcaNNet' , 'polr' , 'pda' , 'pda2' , 'multinom' , 'ppr' , 'rlm' , 'C5.0Rules' , 'C5.0Tree' , 'gbm' , 'evtree' )

for(m in cc){
tbmodel <- train(target ~ ., data = trainSplit, method = m, trControl = ctrl)
}
```

Comment: What function are you running that shows this prompt? This is not a default message for all R functions.

Comment: I am trying to apply caret models to my data http://topepo.github.io/caret/bytag.html

Comment: Well, if you are using the `caret` package, it looks like that message is coming from [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/c65a05e4fc62a4f109a944b6178e1e328505c671/pkg/caret/R/modelLookup.R). There does not appear to be a way to select yes non-interactively. If you know what models you are going to run, you will need to install them ahead of time.

Comment: I think I have an answer to this but I need a reproducible example of how you run into this

Comment: Hack-R please see the edits